# Logging in with email and not username

Tags: users, emails

I tried the module LoginToboggan to log in entering the email and not the username (that I use as Facebook ID). The problem is that the module allows to log in with either the email or the username.

How can I log in with just the email?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that, try [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration), from module description:

> Allow users to register and login using only an email address. Users can then log-in using their email address and password for authentication.
>
> A username is generated and assigned based on the user name part of
>   the email address and their user ID

is avilable in D7, D8

Comment: Thank you. I installed it but the problem seems to be the same. The connexion is possible with both email and username.

Comment: look in module settings.

Comment: In D8 the only option is to allow logging in with email or username. Not just email.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/login_email

Also this module is very useful https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration

hope it helps you.